Wacom Signature Capture issue only on windows server
I have a requirement to integrate a Wacom tablet with a web application to capture the signature in an MVC web form.
The integration has been implemented using 'Wacom Ink SDK for Windows' which works fine on the local machine.
However, when I move the same code to the dev server (Win server 2019), it throws a DynCaptPadError error.
The license key used is a premium key and it is no throwing this error in local through IISExpress.
Even the Wacom sign pro PDF software provided by them doesn't seem to work on the server.
How does the sdk validate the license? Do we need to open any ports to external site from the server? What am I missing?
Below is the implementation of the same for reference.
        private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SigCtl sigCtl = new SigCtl();
            sigCtl.Licence = "XXXXX";
            DynamicCapture dc = new DynamicCaptureClass();
            DynamicCaptureResult res = dc.Capture(sigCtl, "Who", "Why", null, null);
            if (res == DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptOK)
            {
                SigObj sigObj = (SigObj)sigCtl.Signature;
                sigObj.set_ExtraData("AdditionalData", "C# test: Additional data");
                String filename = "sig1.png";
                try
                {
                    sigObj.RenderBitmap(filename, 200, 150, "image/png", 0.5f, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, 10.0f, 10.0f, RBFlags.RenderOutputFilename | RBFlags.RenderColor32BPP | RBFlags.RenderEncodeData);

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        sigImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
               
            }
            else
            {
                print("Signature capture error res=" + (int)res + "  ( " + res + " )");
                switch (res)
                {
                    case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptCancel: print("signature cancelled"); break;
                    case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptError: print("no capture service available"); break;
                    case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptPadError: print("signing device error"); break;
                    default: print("Unexpected error code "); break;
                }
            }
        }

Note: The SDK, device drivers, .NET framework are installed on the server, which is same as the working local pc.
Edit: The response is DynCaptPadError. This seems to happen only when hosted on IIS. It works fine from IIS Express. Please advise

You should contact the vendor if there's a license issue

@SimonMourier The response is DynCaptPadError. This seems to happen only when hosted on IIS. It works fine from IIS Express. Please advise
